# How can I open WinXP's Services control panel applet on the Standard tab by default?

Tags: windows-xp, services, control-panel

When opening the Services control panel applet it opens on the Extended tab by default. I find that tab wastes a great deal of real estate for no real value-added.  All the same information is available on the Standard tab already, without the superfluous whitespace.  Can anyone tell me if it's possible, and how, to tweak the UI so that the Services applet will open on the Standard tab by default.  (I'm envisioning a Registry key/value, but maybe it's somewhere else, if at all?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate that too.  Here's how to fix it:

1. Browse to C:\Windows\System32
2. Right-click on **services.msc**, choose **Author**
3. Change to Standard mode
4. File menu, Save

It will default to the Standard mode from now on.

Comment: You are a king among men, @djhowell.  This seemingly little thing has plagued me for ages.  Thanks!

Comment: Works if I open with services.msc, but not if I access through My Computer > Manage (via right-click context menu) -- going that way still opens the Extended tab first.  For that, Author the compmgmt.msc file (same path), make the same changes, save.

Comment: Alright, @~quack, you're pretty good too. :)  Thanks!

Comment: sorry, it was the first thing i checked!  and it made me sad when it didn't work. :(  but i figured hey, if i can author one, maybe i can author the other too!  so yaaay! +1 for authoring!