# Is there a way to get the Services Manager window to remember its state?

Tags: windows-xp, services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open WinXP’s Services control panel applet on the Standard tab by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/50130/how-can-i-open-winxps-services-control-panel-applet-on-the-standard-tab-by-defau)

The Services Manager always opens up in "Extended" view in the top left of the screen, too small to read, and I end up changing to "Standard" view and resizing the window. But then when I close and open again, it's gone back to "Extended" view in a small window.

Is there a known way to get it to remember its state when I last closed it?

Comment: Exact dupe of my own question. :)
http://superuser.com/questions/50130/how-can-i-open-winxps-services-control-panel-applet-on-the-standard-tab-by-defau

Comment: Dang. Didn't see it in the search. Lock it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there is!

- In **Control Panel -> Administrative Tools**, right click the services snap-in and select **Author**

  [image]
- Change the view to **Standard** then go to **File -> Save**

  [image]

It should now open with standard view by default.

Comment: You're welcome! any time :)