# How to make services.msc not to ask for admin rights?

Tags: windows-7

I modified this file, but somehow now when I run it the system prompts for admin rights which was not the case formerly. What should I do to avoid this prompt?

Comment: How did you modify it, exactly?

Comment: @and31415 I copied it in another location, deleted the old file and then copied it back.

Comment: Heh, so you changed ACL permissions on it somehow. Find a like file and try to recreate the permissions on it if you can.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs I re-created the permissions totally but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that changes the ACL DACL settings on a system file can lead to such issues.

[There are ways to modify a Microsoft Console Snapin without touching the original file so access doesn't get messed up.](https://superuser.com/questions/318343/how-can-i-modify-the-services-msc-file-in-windows-7)

**One of the tools that Microsoft provides to help correct such issues is** `SFC` (System File Checker).

Run Command Prompt as administrator and run `sfc /scannow` at the command prompt.

Comment: I already restored the permissions totally by making them the same as for compmgmt.msc. This does not help.

Comment: Did you read the last two lines and try running SFC? The administrator is not supposed to mess with a lot of system files, only the installer service can properly work with them to maintain proper DACL ACL rights.

Comment: this is a good advise, but I already rolled the system back to a restore poit, which cured the problem.

Comment: Reworded the answer and added a link to advice on changing the snapin without messing with file permissions on the original system file.

Comment: One can create an own file with changed snapin but it will bring an UAC prompt at any start, so no difference from just switch to the standard tab at any launch.

Comment: Yeah, all this security stuff kind of gets annoying after while, except when you run without it and find out the consequences. I have this one backup program that pulls up a UAC for admin access even when you're only backing up user folders and have full permissions as that limited user. Groan!

Comment: By the way, after some recent updates Windows 8 totally remembers the mmc layout!